# Not getting session value in master page load in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, session

I am developing an application in asp.net using c#. In my application some of the pages are simple html and some of them are aspx associated with a master page. In the html page i am setting up the session through ajax call and also I am getting the current session through same process. Setting up the session and getting session between html pages are working fine. But when an html page redirecting to the aspx page then master page not getting the session. How can I pass session from html to aspx master page. Please help.

Web Method Code:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]
public string getUserID()
{
    try
    {
        if (Session["User_ID"] != null)
        {
            uid = Convert.ToString(Session["User_ID"]);
            if (uid.Contains("temp@"))
            {
                return "NA";
            }
            else
            {
                return uid;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return "NA";
        }
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException)
    {
        return "NA";
    }
}

[WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string ValidateCustomer(string cust_email, string cust_passkeys, string temp_userid)
{
    sql_query = "select Password_Hash from Customer_Master where Customer_Email='" + cust_email + "'";
    result_ds = new DataSet();
    result_ds = DBAccess.selectQuery(sql_query);
    bool pwdStatus;

    if (result_ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        string pwdHash = Convert.ToString(result_ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]);
        pwdStatus = PasswordHash.PasswordHash.ValidatePassword(cust_passkeys.Trim(), pwdHash);

        if (pwdStatus)
        {
            sql_query = "update Temporary_Shopping_Cart set Customer_ID='" + cust_email.Trim() + "' where Customer_ID='" + temp_userid.Trim() + "'";
            status = DBAccess.executeQuery(sql_query);

            Session["User_ID"] = cust_email.ToString();
            return "TRUE";
        }
        else
            return "FALSE";
    }
    else
    {
        return "FALSE";
    }

}
```

JQuery Code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "Services/Utils_General.asmx/getUserID",
    data: "{}",
    dataType: "JSON",
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        var uid = data.d.toString();
        alert(uid);
        if (uid != "NA") {
            document.getElementById("loginPanel").innerHTML = "<a href='#' id='dropdownMenu1' data-toggle='dropdown'>" + uid + "</a><ul class='dropdown-menu' role='menu' aria-labelledby='dropdownMenu1'><li role='presentation'><a role='menuitem' tabindex='-1' href='my-profile.aspx'>My Profile</a></li><li role='presentation'><a role='menuitem' tabindex='-1' href='shipping-billing.aspx'>Shipping & Billing Info</a></li><li role='presentation'><a role='menuitem' tabindex='-1' href='#'>Order History</a></li><li role='presentation'><a role='menuitem' tabindex='-1' href='#'>Change Password</a></li><li role='presentation'><a href='#Logout' id='btnLogout'>Logout</a></li></ul>";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("loginPanel").innerHTML = "<a href='#' data-toggle='dropdown' class='dropdown-toggle'>Login</a><ul class='dropdown-menu top-login-form'><li id='loginAlertArea'></li><li><form action='#'><div class='form-group'><input id='txtLoginUserID' type='text' placeholder='Login ID' class='form-control' /><div id='validator_txtLoginUserID'></div></div><div class='form-group'><input id='txtLoginPassword' type='password' placeholder='Password' class='form-control' /><div id='validator_txtLoginPassword'></div></div><div class='form-group'><input type='button' class='btn btn-success' id='btnLogin' data-loading-text='Signing In...' value='Login' /><button type='button' class='btn btn-link pull-right'>Forgot Password?</button></div><div class='form-group text-center'><button type='button' class='btn btn-link member'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></span> Become a member!</button></div></form></li></ul>";
        }
    },
    error: function (result, d, s) {
        alert(s);
    }
});
```

Master Page Reference:

```
<script src="js/App_JS/LoginStore.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The JQuery references has been added to the master page, but it is not giving the expected result.
Please help.

Comment: Post master page code and also where you are setting the session value.

Comment: @MairajAhmad In the master page I have only put the references of the javascript file where the JQuery code is written.

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you are trying to do here. Sessions like these are typically stored by cookie values provided by the server. Not requested via Ajax. Can you please explain the overall aim more clearly?

Comment: where are setting values :)?

Comment: I have added the code block for setting the Session Variable called ValidateCustomer. Please go through the updated post.